# Module object has no attribute [CANTERA]

Tags: python, cantera

I've been trying out the simpliest basics of Cantera.
I'm using Cantera 2.2.1 installed on CAE Linux (Xubuntu 12.04) along with iPython.

I first import:

```
import cantera as ct
```

Then I try creating a gas:

```
gas = ct.Solution('gri30.xml')
```

That is just a tutorial copycat. Yet it seems not to work at all. What i get is

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Solution'
```

I wish to know what can a reason behind this all be.