# Cantera 'module' object has no attribute 'Solution'

Tags: cantera

My question is the same as the one here.

[Module object has no attribute [CANTERA]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35724270/module-object-has-no-attribute-cantera?newreg=e8480234e8804eddb3c41a5c4c216c51)

Ray Speth commented but the OP of that post never responded so I'm hoping that maybe Ray could help me out.

I installed Cantera and did tried to make a gas doing the following

```
import cantera as ct
gas1 = ct.Solution('gri30.xml')
```

and I got the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Solution'
```

I did as the comment suggested and got the following outputs

```
print(ct.__file__)
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cantera/__init__.py

print(ct.__version__)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__version__'
```

Comment: Hi! Cantera developer here. You're much more likely to get a response by posting on the [Google User Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/cantera-users) but please note that you need to include a lot more information, specifically about how you installed Cantera, what version you're using, and what OS you're using.

Answer (score 0):

- Check the versions and compatibility of your Python and Cantera.
- Also, check that your mechanism file is correctly merged (the thermo and kinetics files to make the .cti file).